# Como passar uma matriz como argumento com o usuário definindo o nº de colunas?

Tags: c++, funções, matriz, parâmetros, array

Vou fazer um programa simples só pra exemplificar meu problema.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void recebeValor( int mat[][col]) // me da erro de comp;
{
   mat[0][0] = 2;
   cout << mat[0][0];
}

int main()
{
cout << "Entre o numero de linhas da matriz A: ";
int lin;
cin >> lin;

cout << "Entre o numero de colunas da matriz A> ";
int col;
cin >> col; 

int mat[lin][col];

recebeValor(mat); // isso me da erro de compilacao
```

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 4):

Decida-se se vai usar C ou C++. Em C dá para fazer isto na maioria dos compiladores:

```
void recebeValor(int size, int mat[][size]) {
   mat[0][0] = 2;
}

int main() {
    int lin = 3;
    int col = 3;
    int mat[lin][col];
    recebeValor(col, mat);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/9D9riR). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/MatrixParametercpp). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Array/MatrixParameter.cpp).

Também dá para usar apenas ponteiros no lugar do *array* e funciona para C++.

Se vai usar C++, não use *array* bruto.

Até dá para criar uma [gambiarra para resolver isto com `template`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6222108/221800). Mas a solução de fato é usar uma estrutura mais abstrata e mais preparada para lidar com isto. Prefira usar um `Vector`.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void recebeValor(vector<vector<int>> mat) {
   mat[0][0] = 2;
   cout << mat[0][0];
}

int main() {
    cout << "Entre o numero de linhas da matriz A: ";
    int lin;
    cin >> lin;
    cout << "Entre o numero de colunas da matriz A> ";
    int col;
    cin >> col; 
    vector<vector<int>> mat(lin, vector<int>(col));
    recebeValor(mat);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/7vh2ti). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/MatrixParameter2cpp). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Array/MatrixParameter2.cpp).

Answer (score 3):

O problema é que você não declarou `col` em lugar nenhum. Por causa disso o compilador vai reclamar, pois `mat` é um parâmetro, mas `col` ele não sabe o que é.

Além disso, em C++, se você quiser definir o tamanho da matriz no parâmetro, terá que fazê-lo estaticamente. Ou seja, o tamanho exato tem que ser conhecido em tempo de compilação. O motivo é que para que o compilador possa fazer a verificação de tipos, ele deve ter conhecimento completo do tipo em tempo de compilação, e portanto o tipo não pode depender de algo que só exista durante a execução.

E o mais importante: Para que o compilador possa calcular quanto espaço de memória cada elemento vai ocupar, ele vai precisar saber em tempo de compilação qual o tamanho que cada posição do parâmetro array ocupa. Como o tipo do parâmetro é uma matriz (array de arrays), então **o compilador necessariamente precisa saber o tamanho exato em tempo de compilação de todas as dimensões com exceção da primeira.**

Assim, isso daqui não é válido:

```
int a, b, c;

// Erro, os valores a, b e c não estão disponíveis em tempo de compilação, só em tempo de execução.
void funcaoQualquer(int mat[a][b][c]) {
}
```

Já isso daqui é válido, pois o compilador sabe exatamente qual é o tamanho de cada dimensão:

```
void funcaoQualquer(int mat[5][5][5]) {
}
```

Isso daqui também é válido. Embora o compilador não saiba o tamanho do array como um todo, ele sabe qual é o tamanho de cada elemento na primeira dimensão.

```
void funcaoQualquer(int mat[][5][5]) {
}
```

Já esses daqui não são válidos. O compilador não tem como saber qual é o tamanho de cada elemento na primeira dimensão:

```
void funcaoQualquer1(int mat[][][5]) {
}

void funcaoQualquer2(int mat[][][]) {
}

void funcaoQualquer3(int mat[5][][]) {
}

void funcaoQualquer4(int mat[5][5][]) {
}

void funcaoQualquer5(int mat[][5][]) {
}
```